# NIC cards in a LINUX server

Tags: linux, ip

I have below doubts, Can someone clarify, please?

1. Four interfaces(say eth1, eth2,eth3,eth4) are configured with different subnet IP addresses in my LINUX server, so does that mean are there four NIC cards in In my server?.
2. Can two Physical interfaces be under one NIC card?
3. if I have two NIC cards in my LINUX server, does that mean there are two independent TCP/IP stacks on my server? what does multiple network stacks on a linux server mean exactly?

Comment: What hardware do you have? You can get lots of differnt type NICs. big ones, small ones, ones with 1 port, ones with 4 ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Four interfaces(say eth1, eth2,eth3,eth4) are configured with different subnet IP addresses in my LINUX server, so does that mean are there four NIC cards in In my server?.

Maybe. More likely on a server are that number of ports are on the main board. In servers dual and quad port cards are also common, so the number of NIC cards can be anywhere between 0 and 4.

`lspci` and/or `dmidecode` will show you what NIC's are present.

> 2. Can two Physical interfaces be under one NIC card?

Yes.

> 3. if I have two NIC cards in my LINUX server, does that mean there are two independent TCP/IP stacks on my server? what does multiple network stacks on a linux server mean exactly?

No.

Linux uses the weak [host model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model) by default.

Comment: Thank you HBruijn. Suppose if I have a NIC card with 4 ports in my LINUX Server and each port is assigned an IP address, then how many Individual TCP/IP stacks does that server have? What does individual TCP/IP stack mean in a Linux server?